# XML parse it into a collection object

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, parsing, object

I was able to parse the following XML into an object thanks MikeH.

When I parse the XML file into an object it only fills the last row into the object.  How could I parse all the rows into a collection object.  The rows should fill into a collection.  In this case all 5-records should be in the collection not just the last record ().  I spent most of the day and I must be missing something on how to get all the rows into the object.

```
  - <ROW>
    <CELL INDEX="0">033331111</CELL> 
    <CELL INDEX="1">Agency 5 LTD</CELL> 
    <CELL INDEX="2">14 Some AVENUE North Brook, FL 65432 3827</CELL> 
    <CELL INDEX="3">A</CELL> 
    <CELL INDEX="4">4412034564</CELL> 
    <CELL INDEX="5" /> 
    <CELL INDEX="6">A - Active</CELL> 
    <CELL INDEX="7">6/1/2008 12:00:00 AM</CELL> 
    </ROW>
```

With Visual Studio 2012 or greater: 
Copy the XML to your clipboard
From within Visual Studio: Edit --> Paste Special --> Paste XML As Classes
Then you'll need to serialize the data from XML to your newly created class to create a new object:

```
var myObject = LoadFromXmlString<DATA_PROVIDERS>(xmlData);

public static T LoadFromXmlString<T>(string xml)
{
  T retval = default(T);
  try
  {
    XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(xml));
    retval = (T)s.Deserialize(ms);
    ms.Close(); 
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    ex.Data.Add("Xml String", xml);
    throw new Exception("Error loading from XML string.  See data.", ex);
  }
  return retval;

}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
-<DATA_PROVIDERS UID="Providers|REP" FORCE_REFRESH="FALSE" DATA_PROVIDER="" FORMATTED="FALSE" REFRESH="TRUE">
 -<DATA_PROVIDER NAME="Prov" SOURCE="Provider" DATE="11/18/2014" DURATION="9s" REFRESH="TRUE" CUBE="1">
  <COLUMN INDEX="0" ID="119" TYPE="String" FORMAT="">Prov ID</COLUMN> 
  <COLUMN INDEX="1" ID="118" TYPE="String" FORMAT="">Prov Name</COLUMN> 
  <COLUMN INDEX="2" ID="113" TYPE="String" FORMAT="">Address Info</COLUMN> 
  <COLUMN INDEX="3" ID="110" TYPE="String" FORMAT="">Enroll Status Code</COLUMN> 
  <COLUMN INDEX="4" ID="119" TYPE="String" FORMAT="">Phone</COLUMN> 
  <COLUMN INDEX="5" ID="110" TYPE="String" FORMAT="">Fax</COLUMN> 
  <COLUMN INDEX="6" ID="109" TYPE="String" FORMAT="">Provider Status</COLUMN> 
  <COLUMN INDEX="7" ID="150" TYPE="Date" FORMAT="m/d/yyyy h:mm:ss am/pm">Provider Start Date</COLUMN> 
  - <ROW>
    <CELL INDEX="0">004042111</CELL> 
    <CELL INDEX="1">CONTOSO West INC</CELL> 
    <CELL INDEX="2">1234 Random Rd. SOMECITY, ZZ 12345 9876</CELL> 
    <CELL INDEX="3">F</CELL> 
    <CELL INDEX="4">5555551234123</CELL> 
    <CELL INDEX="5">5555551234</CELL> 
    <CELL INDEX="6">F - Agency Action</CELL> 
    <CELL INDEX="7">5/31/2011 12:00:00 AM</CELL> 
    </ROW>
  - <ROW>
    <CELL INDEX="0">004011117</CELL> 
    <CELL INDEX="1">CONTOSO North INC</CELL> 
    <CELL INDEX="2">4321 Random Rd. SOMECITY, ZZ 12345 9876</CELL> 
    <CELL INDEX="3">F</CELL> 
    <CELL INDEX="4">5555551234123</CELL> 
    <CELL INDEX="5">5555551234</CELL> 
    <CELL INDEX="6">F - Agency Action</CELL> 
    <CELL INDEX="7">5/31/2011 12:00:00 AM</CELL> 
    </ROW>
  - <ROW>
    <CELL INDEX="0">033337111</CELL> 
    <CELL INDEX="1">Agency 3 INC</CELL> 
    <CELL INDEX="2">200 street 5F Cityabc, NY 12033</CELL> 
    <CELL INDEX="3">A</CELL> 
    <CELL INDEX="4">2128545555</CELL> 
    <CELL INDEX="5" />
    <CELL INDEX="6">A - Active</CELL> 
    <CELL INDEX="7">10/27/2003 12:00:00 AM</CELL> 
    </ROW>
  - <ROW>
    <CELL INDEX="0">033334111</CELL> 
    <CELL INDEX="1">Agency 4 LLC</CELL> 
    <CELL INDEX="2">419 street Town, CT 17033 3945</CELL> 
    <CELL INDEX="3">U</CELL> 
    <CELL INDEX="4" /> 
    <CELL INDEX="5">7172304056</CELL> 
    <CELL INDEX="6">X - Did Not Re-enroll</CELL> 
    <CELL INDEX="7">2/24/2009 12:00:00 AM</CELL> 
    </ROW>
  - <ROW>
    <CELL INDEX="0">033331111</CELL> 
    <CELL INDEX="1">Agency 5 LTD</CELL> 
    <CELL INDEX="2">14 Some AVENUE North Brook, FL 65432 3827</CELL> 
    <CELL INDEX="3">A</CELL> 
    <CELL INDEX="4">4412034564</CELL> 
    <CELL INDEX="5" /> 
    <CELL INDEX="6">A - Active</CELL> 
    <CELL INDEX="7">6/1/2008 12:00:00 AM</CELL> 
    </ROW>
 </DATA_PROVIDER>
</DATA_PROVIDERS>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to mark your `Cells` collection with the [`XmlElement("CELLS")`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute to inform `XmlSerializer` that the collection should be serialized as a sequence of identically named elements, rather than a single element with nested subelements, like so:

```
public class Cell
{
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("INDEX")]
    public int Index { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("ROW")]
public class Row
{
    [XmlElement("CELL")]
    public List<Cell> Cells { get; set; }
}
```

In addition, I notice your `Cell` objects contain their array index as an attribute, which seems redundant since the position of each cell in its list of cells also conveys this information.  Do you actually want that in your run-time classes -- or would you rather that this information be generated for serialization only?  If you prefer the latter, you may serialize & deserialize the cells as an array of proxies that contain the array index as an attribute property, like so:

```
public class Cell 
{
    public Cell() {}

    public Cell(Cell other)
    {
        this.Text = other.Text;
    }

    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class XmlCell : Cell // For serialization
{
    public XmlCell() : base() {}

    public XmlCell(Cell other, int index) : base(other)
    {
        this.Index = index;
    }

    [XmlAttribute("INDEX")]
    public int Index { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("ROW")]
public class Row
{
    List<Cell> cells;

    [XmlIgnore]
    public List<Cell> Cells
    {
        get
        {
            if (cells == null)
                Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref cells, new List<Cell>(), null);
            return cells;
        }
    }

    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    [XmlElement("CELL")]
    public XmlCell[] XmlCells // proxy array for serialization.
    {
        get
        {
            var xmlCells = new XmlCell[Cells.Count];
            for (int iCell = 0; iCell < xmlCells.Length; iCell++)
                xmlCells[iCell] = new XmlCell(Cells[iCell], iCell);
            return xmlCells;
        }
        set
        {
            Cells.Clear();
            foreach (var xmlCell in value)
            {
                Cells.EnsureCount(xmlCell.Index + 1);
                Cells[xmlCell.Index] = new Cell(xmlCell);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally a couple extension methods:

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static void Resize<T>(this List<T> list, int count)
    {
        if (list == null || count < 0)
            throw new ArgumentException();
        int oldCount = list.Count;
        if (count > oldCount)
        {
            list.Capacity = count;
            for (int i = oldCount; i < count; i++)
                list.Add(default(T));
        }
        else if (count < oldCount)
        {
            for (int i = oldCount - 1; i >= count; i--)
                list.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }

    public static void EnsureCount<T>(this List<T> list, int count)
    {
        if (list == null || count < 0)
            throw new ArgumentException();
        if (count > list.Count)
            list.Resize(count);
    }
}
```